# Chrome app file system in kiosk mode

Tags: google-chrome-os

i have an app (signage player) that loads video and placed it in folder which user pointed on the beginning (named 'media').

Then i define source attr of video element as "media/name_of_file.mp4"

In plain mode is works well - local video plays. But i and don't know why. In Kiosk mode app can't find a files at all.

Do you have any ideas about it?

What features has or hasn't file system in kiosk mode - it's really hard to debug it there.

Many thanks for any information about file system in kiosk mode.

Answer (score 0):

https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chromebook-central/zv1nxWBAce4;context-place=forum/chromebook-central

According to this answer, app in kiosk mode hasn't any access to file system.(but from my experience it isn't quite true, i can wright files and folders, read them via file api)
Main problem that i can't reach them from dom src property.

But anyway google demand additional license for this option, so any 
kludges can be blocked in further versions of chrome os...

Answer (score 0):

Create a shortcut to your Chrome executable, right click it, select "Properties" and then make sure the target field looks like this (for example):

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --kiosk "file:///C:/Users/JohnDoe/Desktop/MyHTMLFile.HTML"
```

The executable must be in double quotes, as well as the file path.

You may need to embed your MP4 inside an HTML5 element on a local HTML file for this to work.